# Summing satellite cloud masks creates weird blocks along water

Tags: raster, sentinel-2

I'm trying to sum 150 Sentinel-2 cloud masks together.

Before I do this I have reclassify every pixel into a 1(cloud) or a 0(no cloud) based on the original value. This results in:
[image]

After that I sum all the images together using a python script. All seemed to work fine at first, but when the total images summed reaches somewhere around 20 a weird pattern starts to appear:
[image]

Along the edges of waterbodies block start to appear as if they have a lower resolution (Every cell should be 20m by 20m) like in the image below. It's not that weird that water has a higher value, but the rough edges are just weird to me.

Does anyone know why this is happening? I'm saving everything as tif (not as Sentinel's jp2 due to data loss). All the images have the same CRS and extent. The script is using Rasterio.

Comment: Have you looked at the data for any anomalies?